# RVM and automatically switching gemsets

Tags: ruby, rvm

Is it possible to have rvm know which gemset it should be using while navigating under a certain directory, much in the same way you can have git the current branch's information just by navigating under that directory?

I understand how git works that way since each directory has its own .git directory in the root, but didn't know if it was possible since .rvm is more of a user-wide configuration.  Or perhaps the answer is to make a .rvm file within each directory?

Comment: Things might have changed since this question was first posed. The [rvm docs](https://rvm.io/workflow/projects#typical-rvm-project-workflow) seem to suggest that `.rvmrc` might not be the best way to go about this, since `.versions.conf`, `.ruby-version` and `.ruby-gemset` all exist for essentially the same purpose.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Create a `.rvmrc` file in each project/branch with contents similar to this:

```
rvm gemset use xxxx
```

Save it. Next time you `cd` into that folder, you'll probably get a security prompt from RVM to make sure you want to use that `.rvmrc`. After accepting, you'll see "Now using gemset 'xxxx'" every time you navigate into that folder.

Comment: yeah, I did it, but it doesn't work fine - every time I enter the project folder I got notification (green colour in terminal) that this  project is using x.x.x version of ruby, but when I want do something I have errors (different range errors: from active record ones to used gems etc.) - but when I type rvm use x.x.x (same version like in after enter project folder notification) everything works fine - do you know how to solve this? :/

Comment: This is the old way to do things. The new way is to use `.ruby-version` and `.ruby-gemset` files. Both must be present. See @Yule's answer below.

Comment: @DylanMarkow: ok, cd work well because of .. cd. But how to run rvm by chdir in other script languages? chdir to directory with .ruby-version and .ruby-gemset doesn't allow to autoload gemsets

Answer (score 33):

For others visiting this, there is a new way to do this, without having to allow arbitrary shell script to be executed in a .rvmrc file.

Create a file named `.ruby-gemset` containing only the gemset name in.

```
gemset
```

Need an up to date version of rvm for this to work.

You can also specify the ruby version by creating a file named `.ruby-version` containing only the ruby version:

```
1.9.3
```

---

This format also has the advantage of being compatible with `rbenv` and `rbfu`.

If you have existing projects using the deprecated `.rvmrc`, you can convert them to the new format using the command:

```
rvm rvmrc to .ruby-version
```

Comment: This answer could use some cleaning up, it's confusing in it's current state. Do you mean, create a file called .ruby-gemset and have it contain only `gemset my_gemset_name`? The same for .ruby-version, have it contain only `1.9.3`?

Comment: As stated, the .ruby-gemset should just contain just the gemset name and .ruby-version should contain just the ruby version

Comment: nothing happens for me when I cd in to the directory, i've followed the directions exactly. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 27):

I find the easiest way to achieve this is to navigate to the project folder and then use the following command:

```
rvm --rvmrc --create <ruby>@<desired-gemset-name>
```

e.g. `rvm --rvmrc --create 1.9.2-p290@testing_gemset`

In one stroke, RVM will create the .rvmrc file, populate it, install the correct ruby version - if necessary - and (usually) switch to the correct ruby version and gemset. I say usually because I find that I sometimes have to `cd .` after performing that command to get RVM to pick up the changes.

Answer (score 1):

Create a .ruby-version file with the contents [ruby version]@[gemset] in the project folder.

Example:

```
$ rvm gemset list

    gemsets for ruby-2.6.3 (found in /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3)
       (default)
       hello
    => sample
       toy

$ echo "2.6.3@sample" > .ruby-version
```

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot get .ruby-version / .ruby-gemset working, consider whether your terminal is using shell login and try running the command in the shell section at http://rvm.io/support/faq:

```
$ rvm get [head|stable] --auto
```

Answer (score -1):

It is possible: http://rvm.io/workflow/rvmrc/:

```
rvm use ruby@gemset
```